# SQL select from table where multiple entries exist

Tags: sql

I have a database of info from the pokemon games.  One of the tables contains the moves that can be learned by each pokemon.  How can I select from this table where a pokemon can learn both of two moves?

My current query is `SELECT * FROM 'learned-moves' WHERE 'Version Group'=? AND ('Move'=? OR 'Move'=?);` but this selects all rows that contain either move.  How can I only return those rows if they both match?

edit:
[image: db schema]

Comment: what does your db look like? got schemas?

Comment: I would use a foreign key lookup table -- giving 3 tables: pokemon, moves, and learned_moves.

Comment: edited to add db schema

Comment: Is learned-moves.Move a foreign key to the "moves" table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an `INNER JOIN` on itself or self-join:

```sql
SELECT l1.Pokemon, l1.'Move' AS 'Move1', l2.'Move' AS 'Move2'
FROM 'learned-moves' l1
INNER JOIN 'learned-moves' l2
  ON l2.Pokemon = l1.Pokemon
  AND l2.'Version Group' = l1.'Version Group'
  AND l1.'Version Group' = ?
  AND l1.'Move' = ?
  AND l2.'Move' = ?
```